# cocoaPods pod file with external library

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have this pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘9.0’

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'testthing' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.2'

end
```

Nothing special. But I want to link Startapp, so I found this code to use it with pods:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "StartApp"
  s.version      = "3.2.0"
  s.summary      = "StartApp SDK for iOS"

  s.description  = <<-DESC
                   StartApp SDK for iOS.
                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "https://www.startapp.com"

  s.license      = { :type => 'Apache License, Version 2.0', :text => <<-LICENSE
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
    LICENSE
  }

  s.author             = { "StartApp" => "https://www.startapp.com" }

  s.platform     = :ios
  # s.platform     = :ios, "5.0"

  s.source       = { :http => "http://s3.startapp.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Resource/SDK_TEMP/IOS-InApp%20SDK-InApp-3.2.0.zip" }
  s.vendored_frameworks = "StartApp.framework"
  s.resource  = "StartApp.bundle"

  s.frameworks = "AdSupport", "StoreKit", "CoreTelephony", "SystemConfiguration", "CoreGraphics", "QuartzCore", "CoreMedia", "AVFoundation"
  s.library = "z"

end
```

But how can I integrate this into the pod file, I have tried the remove the s and place it in my pod file but that doesn't work?

Comment: What did you try and put in your pod file?  Put `pod 'StartApp'` underneath the AFNetworking one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `source 'http://s3.startapp.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Resource/SDK_TEMP/IOS-InApp%20SDK-InApp-3.2.0.zip'`in podfile upper platform, and add `pod 'StartApp'`under target

Comment: If you have question, feel free to ask :)